# PostgreSQL query terminating abruptly because statement timeout

Tags: performance, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize a query that takes too much time. This is what I have

- **table1(field1, field2... field14): contains about 8.5 million rows**
- **table2(f1, f2, f3): contains about 2.5 million rows**

The query is this one

```
SELECT 
   value1,
   value2,
   value3,
   value4,
   value5, 
   hstore(
       ARRAY['field9', 'field10', 'field11', 'field12', 'field13', 'field14'],     
       ARRAY[field9, field10, field11, field12, field13, field14) as metadata, 
   value7, 
  (select array((select row(f1, f2) from table2 p where p.f3 = field7))) as values_array 
FROM table1
```

And explain analyze tells me this

```
                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using table1_pkey on table1  (cost=67846.38..395773.45 rows=8419127 width=88) (actual time=7122.704..22670.680 rows=8419127 loops=1)
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Result  (cost=67846.29..67846.29 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=7009.063..7009.065 rows=1 loops=1)
           InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
             ->  Seq Scan on table2 p  (cost=0.00..67846.29 rows=12689 width=20) (actual time=14.971..5069.840 rows=2537787 loops=1)
                   Filter: (f3 = field7)
```

So, there's a **sequential scan over table2** (in the query to get values_array), **instead of a index scan**. Could it be because the SELECT returns more than approximately 5-10% of all rows in the table? (I've heard that, under those conditions, a sequential scan is faster than index scan, because the amount of I/O operations required for each row).

**Anyway, is there anything obviously wrong in that query? The server just kill it because timeout**

If I limit the amount of rows return by adding **LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0**, it takes about **3 mins**, but to cover the whole table (remember: 8.5 million records) by moving OFFSET, I would need about 8000 iterations. 3 mins each one means more than 15 days... It's just not acceptable. Besides, big OFFSETS would mean poor performance too.

Any insights? In PostgreSQL list, they've recommended me to replace the inner query with a JOIN, and use composite types instead of array. I'm working on it, but I'm kind of stuck with this, and any comment is welcome.

Many thanks!

Comment: "on the postgresql list they've recommended ...." <-- link?

Comment: Yes, sorry. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, by table-prefixing all columns. The query now looks like this

```
SELECT 
   a.value1,
   a.value2,
   a.value3,
   a.value4,
   a.value5, 
   hstore(
       ARRAY['field9', 'field10', 'field11', 'field12', 'field13', 'field14'],     
       ARRAY[a.field9, a.field10, a.field11, a.field12, a.field13, a.field14) as metadata, 
  a.value7, 
  (select array((select row(p.f1, p.f2) from table2 p where p.f3 = a.field7))) as values_array 
FROM table1 a
```

The problem was table2.f3 and table1.field7 really have the same name. Further information at [this post of PostgreSQL general list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMhtMNP8yu0jSNsRt5caPN37cr5LG40vRUgpnexPZimec+K26g@mail.gmail.com)

Comment: by "prefixing" you mean using aliases, I assume?

Comment: yes, using aliases for tables and doing alias.column